# Kendo Editor and carot position for existing html content

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have scenario where I pre-popuate the editor with html content.
 For e.g.

```
<P>The <ins>black</ins> spotted fox <del>leaped</del>
```

If the user now wants to add an extra content next to word leaped then formatting from  element would be retained so any additional text would have strikethrough applied to it by default. Is there a way to avoid this without the user having to manually then reset the strikethrough option in the tools ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just add a space at the end?

```
<textarea id="editor">
  <P>The <ins>black</ins> spotted fox <del>leaped</del>&nbsp;
</textarea>
```

I'm not sure why you got voted down for this one.

Comment: I did try that originally and seemed an ok solution but problem is do end up with extra spaces in the content so was trying to avoid that. Not sure why I got voted down either, but annoying that they aren't big enough to say a reason for vote down:)

Comment: You can always trim the end of the content with jQuery.trim().  Would that work?

Comment: It would for content at the end of the line but I assume trim won't work for whitespaces in the middle of the content.